# Why did my Wi-Fi connection improve after installation of a Wi-Fi range extender?

Tags: wireless-networking, dual-band, wireless-extender

[image]

I live in a flat downstairs. The Internet router (Virgin Media) is placed upstairs. The data throughput was miserable (about 50 Mbps).

Then I installed a Wi-Fi Range Extender (dual band). After  installation I got an amazing 300 Mbps (see snapshot). The difference was brutal: from not being able to browse the Internet in some places of the flat, to having a perfect signal.

My question is why? How is this possible?

The Wi-Fi Range extender is not even close to the router! My guess is: the router (SuperHub3) is emitting 2.4 and 5 GHz, the 5 GHz goes through the walls and reaches the extender without problem, then the extender has the signal and repeats it with 2.4 GHz which is the only frequency my Mac can recognize. It is true?

[image]

As suggested by other users I attach the broadband performance test before and after the installation of the range extender.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's 2.4 GHz and usually 5 GHz has a harder time passing obstacles. You're not really seeing any information about the connectivity between your extender and router. The optimal connection is because there are less obstacles between you and your repeater now. Depending on the model you would only have those 300 Mbit between your and the repeater.

Comment: @Seth You are right: the 300 MBps is just the trhoughput between extender and device. But before installation I hardly could do Whatsup or Skype audio calls, now I can do video calls without any problem. The difference is huge.

Comment: Your Mac supports 5 GHz. All Macs (starting in 2006 with the first Intel-based Macs) support 5GHz Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what a range extender is designed to do. You put it where it can get decent signal to the main AP, and it joins the main AP and republishes the same network name. Now your clients can join a closer AP (the range extender), and the range extender takes their packets and relays them to the main AP. That way everybody's in decent range of somebody who can get their packets where they need to go, so everything works more reliably.

It's like when you can't kick the ball all the way down the football pitch, so you kick it to a teammate halfway, and she kicks it the rest of the way. You don't have to wonder how in the world you got the ball all the way down the pitch. You didn't do it all by yourself. Your teammate relayed it for you.

An interesting experiment would be to turn off your range extender, place your Mac exactly where the range extender is, and see if your web browsing and Skype work just as well from there as they did when connected to the range extender. Maybe run some proper performance tests to quantify it. If your Mac doesn't do as well in the same location as your range extender, it may mean that your range extender has a better RF subsystem (antennas, radio transmit and receive amplifiers, etc.) than your Mac does. Or maybe there's an interoperability problem between your Mac and the Virgin Media router, that the range extender doesn't have.

Comment: I believe your guess about the better antenna and transmitter chip may have some merits. While I don't have a Mac, I do have an iPhone. (Both Mac and iPhone are made by Apple.) There is a certain spot in my place of residence that all other devices except the iPhone get a wireless signal.